# Archive validation failed with errors: -568h size modifier

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes-store

I get this error message when trying to validate an Archive:

[image]

However, I've added a `Default-568h@2x.png` image which is definitely in the `Copy Bundle Resources` section.

What's the problem?

====

UPDATE

Dimensions of the new Default image are: 640 × 1136.

Answer (score 0):

Did u check the resolution of the image ? try restarting the Xcode.